# What is the most common logic family in modern CPUs?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, cmos

I know there are a lot of logic families, from the old RTL to LVC, but which is the most common of them?

Can you also explain the reasons?

I also wanted to know: which is the fastest and which has the lowest power consumption?

Comment: What have you searched on this topic so far?

Comment: Look-up 'PCI-express' and 'Ethernet' physical layers. Other than a CPU core they are the fastest devices around, excluding stuff for Doppler Radar, which is super-conducting and needs to be sprayed with liquid nitrogen while working.

Comment: @Sparky256: **Other than a CPU core** But he specifically asked about CPU cores.

Comment: @jbord39. Oops, missed that in the title.

Answer (score 7):

Silicon is the most commonly used substrate because it is made from sand, cheap, and easy (grows its own oxide).  It also happens to make great FETs, which naturally form CMOS logic in a digital environment.

**The reasons CMOS are used in Silicon:**

CMOS is great for modern CPUs, and almost certainly the most common logic family, especially in the lower nm (22nm, 14nm, 10nm). 
There are a lot of reasons that combine to make this true:

- Rail to rail logic levels (always either a path to the supply or ground)
- Simple to understand and there are few constraints on their usage
- Very predictable and nearly foolproof -- there is nothing dangerous about CMOS
- When not switching the only power consumed is leakage
- Inputs are just a capacitive load
- Less power than dynamic logic
- Easily consumed by synthesis tools
- Ratioed logic.  This means if the voltage scales down (or up), all of the logic gate characteristics scale proportionally.  As an example, the switching voltage of an equally ratioed inverter is half the supply voltage.
- In general individual gates do not require a clock (unlike domino).  Flip flops still do.  This makes a huge difference when you consider routing congestion is the biggest issue in newer processes.  The wire delay rises with respect to gate delay in each new technology and there is no reason why this will change anytime soon.
- I can't stress enough the benefit of not needing a clock.  Check out this image to see the extraordinary increase in wire vs. gate delay (this is only to 100nm; we are at 7nm these days).  Similar reason makes any type of differential logic less appealing.

[image: gate and wire delay vs process]

**Dynamic logic (different implementations) is commonly used for memory/caches.**

The fastest will depend a lot on the design and the process.  For example, is it more routing limited or gate limited?  If you can get away with it (more gate limited), domino logic will most likely be faster.  If it is wiring limited, then you will force routing congestion to convert to domino logic, since each gate now needs an extra clock signal.  So, in this case, you may want to go with Mono-Static Skewed CMOS.  This is like CMOS but skewed for only a single edge.  Typically the logic will be duplicated for both polarities, and captured with an SR latch.  This increases the area and power but can provide better speed.

Also, transmission gate logic is faster in a lot of cases, especially for multiplexers/demultiplexers and the high-z element in flip flops.  This is not technically CMOS logic but is pretty ubiquitous at this point with modern CPUs, especially datapaths.  Depending on who you ask some may consider that CMOS logic.

For less power consumption, I still think CMOS would probably be used.  If delay is not an issue you can use weaker gates to reduce leakage current, or stack the FETs.  Or use clock/power gating, but this is more of a technique and not so much of a logic family.

Comment: "_CMOS is the most common._" Do you have a source for this? It may very well be correct, but I haven't seen a chart with relative popularities of CMOS, BiCMOS, ECL, TTL, etc, and I would be interested if one did exist. Also, CMOS typically comprises a group of logic families (depending on how you define a family; OP could be referring to monolithic logic families or semiconductor families): AC, HC, 4000B are all CMOS monolithic logic families.

Comment: Actually, I guess the question becomes even more muddled by the "in modern CPUs". A modern CPU doesn't really have a "logic family" in my opinion. But yes, I suppose that most modern CPUs (which are typically small FinFET technologies) could be placed under the CMOS umbrella.

Comment: @uint128_t No one builds modern CPU's with monolithic components...  And no, i don't have a chart.  But i can just about gurantee you every CPU produced by Intel, AMD, Qualcomm, IBM, ARM, etc is primarily CMOS

Comment: Yeah, I think you answered the question as best as possible. +1

Comment: Yes, I asked whether it was AC, HC, or HCT, etc.

But thank you for this answer, which is very complete yet!
(What is a monolithic component? I couldn't find that)

Comment: I just couldn't understand why the interconnect delay is increasing.

Comment: The interconnect delay is not increasing with newer technologies.  In fact it reduces with each technology.  But, relative to the gate delay it is increasing.  Why?  Because logic gates are getting faster more quickly than the wire delay.  Also designs are getting more complex leading to more wiring.

Comment: And wires/via resistance is determined primarily by the cross sectional area : length/(width*thickness).  So when wires are shrunken, the resistance increase is ~squared.  At high f the skin effect makes the cross sectional area less important and the wire uses more of the skin, which is defined by the surface area of the cross section.

Comment: Monolithic means a single chip.  Like the logic series you can buy at digikey.  And modern CPUs don't use monolithic chips.  HC, AC, HCT are all CMOS just using different technologies.  Bit none of those are used directly in CPUs.

Comment: So, which technology does it look like most in a CPU such as my intel i3 4th gen?

Comment: I mean it's all built from CMOS, and CMOS would be the dominant logic family.  This is mixed in with dynamic logic on the caches, pass-gate logic in more custom areas or flip flops.  There may even be more exotic logic families included that I don't know about.  Intel doesn't build the CPU from monolithic pieces, it fabricates it using its own technology on a single die.  The monolithic chip series HC, HCT, AC just change the technology inside and maybe how the inputs and outputs interact.  For example voltage scales, this is possible due to smaller FETs.  Intel uses 14nm or less on most chips

Comment: Check out On-chip design styles on wikipedia.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_family#On-chip_design_styles

Comment: I believe PECL with a 1.35 volt 'common' return is typical of parts working at 600MHZ to 4 GHZ, usually in a differential mode, capacitive coupling of 1nF with a 22 ohm load to 1.35 volts. Applies to PCI-Express as well, but Intel keeps re-writing the books with denser chips and faster speeds. The bottleneck is the mobo itself.

Comment: That might be the I/O interface.  But that is not the CPU voltage.  Right now CPU's are @ ~3GHz.  And gates are typically 5-25fF input cap.  How that talks to the outside world is a different beast.